# How to make this diagram in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

Please could someone make this diagram in LaTeX and if you have some other thought to make it better than I draw it I'll be grateful. Here is how figure 1 and 2

[image]
Thanks to Mr John Wickerson who  provide me best style of diagram 
[image]

if possible different style with comment thanks

```
      \usepackage{tikz}
      \usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings}
      % for double arrows a la chef
      % adapt line thickness and line width, if needed
      \tikzstyle{vecArrow} = [thick, decoration={markings,mark=at position
      1 with {\arrow[semithick]{open triangle 60}}},
      double distance=1.4pt, shorten >= 5.5pt,
      preaction = {decorate},
      postaction = {draw,line width=1.4pt, white,shorten >= 4.5pt}]
     \tikzstyle{innerWhite} = [semithick, white,line width=1.4pt, shorten >= 4.5pt]
```

Comment: Wow. I'm sorry but who gave a +2 to this question? This is not fair to the OP either -- they need to learn to improve their "questioning ability".

Comment: Off-topic: Hi Educ :). To reduce downvotes and increase reputation `learn by practice while you earn rep`. For eg: Try to stretch yourself by adding a [Full MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) _now_ by improving on current answer(by John Wickerson) if possible. @recluze: comment might be ok without downvoting(or atleast no upvote) as a first try code was there and thus may be awarded `+2` previously.

Comment: BTW what is the `specific` `technical` title of figure/diagram ? so that we should rename the title to make it clear and make it beneficial for future users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [column sep=7mm, row sep=5mm] {
  \node (se) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Strong existence}; &
  \node (yw) [draw, shape=circle] {Y-W}; &
  \node (ul) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Uniqueness in law}; \\
  \node (d1) [draw, shape=circle] {Defn}; & &
  \node (d2) [draw, shape=circle] {Defn}; \\
  \node (we) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Weak existence}; &
  \node (ec) [draw, shape=circle] {E-C}; &
  \node (pu) [draw, shape=rectangle] {Pathwise uniqueness}; \\
};
\draw[->, thick] (se) -- (d1);
\draw[->, thick] (d1) -- (we);
\draw[->, thick] (we) -- (yw);
\draw[->, thick] (yw) -- (se);
\draw[->, thick] (se) -- (ec);
\draw[->, thick] (ul) -- (ec);
\draw[->, thick] (ec) -- (pu);
\draw[->, thick] (pu) -- (yw);
\draw[->, thick] (pu) -- (d2);
\draw[->, thick] (d2) -- (ul);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks  Mr John Wickerson to provide me best style of diagram

Comment: how to add it to Beamer class i got bad figure by the way i use  \documentclass[leqno,mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphics,bm}
\usetheme{Luebeck}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

Comment: @Educ I'm not sure. I suggest you open a new question.

Comment: @ John Wickerson Thanks i already did and the same for animated if you have any idea please help me to animated